# What are the techniques to predict revenue of a new shop using nearest shops?

Tags: prediction, spatial

I am trying assign a revenue for a new shop based on location. I have the data of nearest few shops. What are the techniques available to propagate/predict revenue a of new shop ?

Comment: k Nearest Neighbors?

Comment: KNN is a classification algorithm. I am more interested in finding out revenue hotspot using spatial data + revenue and get the revenue of the new shop. Thus i want to reduce the revenue of the new shop if it is far away from a revenue hotspot. So I am looking for a more sophisticated method rather than my linear decay function.

Comment: knn is not a classification algorithm, it can be used for regression too. In which case it averages the k nearest based on inverse of distance.

Comment: So simply I need to get the k nearest neighbours and get the mean revenue and assign it to the new shop? Other than KNN what are the other methods ?